# How to prevent access to a "child window", if user has not made selection on Parent window

Tags: php, parent-child, isset

I'm trying to include a small PHP code at the beginning of a certain file (which is a "new window"), which would prevent the user from directly accessing the file, if he inputs the URL directly into his browser.

In other words : my website functions in such a way that, first the user has to make a radio-selection on the parent window, and click "**submit**", which opens  a new "child" window.

But, first the user has to be logged in!

In order to prevent the window from opening, I wrote this code at the very beginning of the PHP file  (for both parent and child windows) :

```
 <?php session_start();

 if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '')) {

        header ("Location: www.example.com/access_denied.php");

 exit() ;
```

If the user is not logged in, and he tries to go directly to a particular URL,  he is re-directed to a file which displays an "**ACCESS DENIED**" text.

However, for this particular situation  (as explained above), the user first needs to make a selection on a parent page.

If he does not choose anything on the parent-page, and simply enters the URL for the "child window" in his browser, he is still able to access the php file directly  (which I do not want)

The radio selection on the parent-page is as follows :

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])  {

 $_SESSION['response'] = $_POST['selection'];
```

On the child_window, I added the following code :

```
 if (!(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] != '') ||     
 (isset($_SESSION['login']) && (!(isset($_POST['selection'])))     {

 header ("Location: www.example.com/access_denied.php");
```

Meaning : even if the user is logged in..........unless he has made a selection on the parent-page, he cannot access the child-window.

But, this code is not working.

I even tried to create a random "**$_SESSION**" variable on the parent-page, which is activated once a radio-selection has been made.............and, on the child-window, I wrote a code, saying :  if this random $_SESSION has not been set, the child-window would give an "**access-denied**" message.

Still, this does not work.  The user is still able to view and access the child-window by typing in the direct URL.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On child_window you are calling this

```
(isset($_SESSION['login']) && (!(isset($_POST['selection'])))     {
```

Call this

```
(isset($_SESSION['login']) && (!(isset($_SESSION['response'])))     {
```

You should call the tag that you have set in the session on the parent window

Comment: Thanks, Nemanja.  But, it didnt work  :(    I called the tag, also